# How to create array inside of stack, not using .data

Tags: mips

is it possible to create array without using.data?

Comment: It looks like you're writing assembly code -- why then is your question tagged [tag:c]?

Comment: The answer to your question is "Yes", so you may want to formulate a better question. Why did you remove most of the original question?